# AJAX fails updating the designated div

Tags: ajax

I used AJAX quite a lot. Take the following code as an example, it sometimes fails updating the designated `content` div. Instead, the whole page is update. It's odd that sometimes it's OK, but other times it's not. The problem seems to occur randomly, and it is very annoying. Can somebody shed some light on it? Thanks.

```
<div id="content"></div>

...

<a href="/admin?arg1=systemSetting" class="adminMenu">
  <button class="adminButton">System settings</button>
</a>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.adminMenu').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load(url);
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I guess you are missing `<input type="button" value="System settings" />` inside the `<button>` tag. (Sarcasm)

Comment: Ok, if serious, you are nesting two clickable elements, this is really bad.

Comment: replace `$("#content").load(url)` with `$.get(url, {}, function(r){ $("#content").html(r); });` should work.

Comment: to prevent redirection odds use this `$("a.adminMenu").click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); /*Do stuff*/  });`

Comment: why do you have a `<button>` inside `<a>`?

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I really shouldn't nest <a ...> with <button ...>. And I'll try the suggestions. But is nesting really the cause of the problem?